# Zuul how not include routes endpoint metrics to gateway metric

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics

I have gateway and routes:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: test-gateway
  cloud:
    loadbalancer:
      retry:
        enabled: true

zuul:
  retryable: true
  set-content-length: true
  routes:
    test:
      path: /**
      serviceId: TEST
      stripPrefix: false
```

Test application has his own prometheus metrics
but zuul takes its and show from test application

how make just zuul metric:

````
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: prometheus
    ```
 this config in gateway appliaction.yml shows test metrics not gateway :(
````